# MySQL: Find a character in a string with similar characters in it

Tags: php, mysql

I got a string here.

```
M/T/W/Th/F/S
```

They're the first letters of Days.
For a scenario. I got two string datas which are `"M/T/W/F"` and `"M/W/Th/F"`;
My problem here is how to differentiate `T` and `Th`.
I don't know how to check only the `"Th"` in the string data
The only method I know is using the MySQL `%` clause but I don't know how to use it in accordance to what I need. I can detect `"T"` using `%T% Like` clause but it will also detect `"Th"`.
Thanks in advance if you help me.

Comment: I suspect there is a whole database normalisation issue here. if you really cant normalise the data consider using  numbers instead (1-7)

Comment: if you must `%T/%` wont match `Th`

Comment: Sir.. you are a saviour... That helps using numbers. that really didn't went to my mind. But since I asked this right now... I want to know whether there's a good loophole to it.

Comment: Can I ask you what's the "/" for? It works but I want to know what's that for.

Comment: thats part of your string

Comment: I see.. but what if the data only as "T" or it ends at "T". For example. "M/T"

Comment: good point, another reason not to do this approach but normalise your data

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve your issue is to search for: %T/% 
and %T in case a string ends with T.

You query will be: 
Where fieldname like '%T/%' or fieldname like '%T'

Comment: Like I said in the comment box above. What if the data only has "T" or it ends at "T". For example. "M/T"

Comment: Yes the case is cover your query condition: where field like '%T/%' or field like '%T'

Comment: Hmmmm. if I use  %T/% and %T. What if the data record is M/T/Th/F?

Comment: When you have something like (M/T/Th/F) it will satisfy the 1st condition: %T/% ... When you have (M/Th/F) it won't because as said in '%T/%' the T letter should be followed by backslash. Now for (T) or (M/T) it will satisfy the 2nd condition: %T. This condition saying that the word should ends with letter T.

Comment: My mind is floating that I forgotten the main thing here.
How about I need to verify "Th" in the "T"? Sorry to argue more but I'm trying to fulfill conditions base on the days and Tuesday and Thursday in their small forms (T and Th) are troublesome

Comment: In %T/% the T letter should be followed by backslash, it will not matches Th/ but T/ will perfectly match.

Comment: Try it with different cases on your data and you can verify it with the results !

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for the comments/opinions